# Extract metadata from audio stream

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I developing an online radio app.  The app plays the streams by giving a url to to Player object:

```
player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(url)
```

How can I extract the metadata like song name and artist name from the stream?  I am developing using BlackBerry OS 5.

Comment: Following link solves the problem :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549542/return-the-correct-value-from-a-javame-thread

Comment: use the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549542/return-the-correct-value-from-a-javame-thread

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you cannot do that. There is no API afaik which gives you that information.

You can attach PlayerListener to a player and get information about many kinds of events(start,stop,update playback time,error and other events) but there is no event which tells you the name of the song.

Are you using rtsp:// url?