# Return the correct value from a JavaME thread

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-jde

I wrote a function which returns a string. And there is a Thread implementation the function, like follows, and I am calling [metaDataTrimmed = getMetaData(url);] this function and store the return value to a string value. My problem is the the function immediately returns the null string, which is its initial value. And I checked my function works properly.

So I try for a Thread.sleep() method using a dirtybit and also tried for Thread.join(). Is there any standard method in BlackBerry to solve the problem, if not what is a good approach to solve the problem?

```
private String getMetaData(final String mediaUrl){  
         String  metaDataT = "";

        Thread metaThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){        
            public void run(){      
            try {
                StreamConnection streamConnection=null;
                HttpConnection httpConnection = null;
                InputStream inputStream =null;
                streamConnection=(StreamConnection)Connector.open(mediaUrl);
                httpConnection=(HttpConnection)streamConnection;        
                httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Icy-metadata", "1");                   
                int httpStatus=httpConnection.getResponseCode();
                if(httpStatus==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK){

                      String mint = httpConnection.getHeaderField("icy-metaint");
                      inputStream = streamConnection.openInputStream();     
                      int length= Integer.parseInt(mint);
                      int b = 0;    
                      int count =0;    
                      while(count++ < length){
                        b = inputStream.read();         
                      }          
                      int metalength = ((int)b)*16;
                     // if(metalength <= 0){waitBitMetaData = 1;return;}
                      byte buf[] = new byte[metalength];               
                      inputStream.read(buf,0,buf.length);              
                      String metaData = new String(buf);         
                      int streamTilleIndex =   metaData.indexOf("StreamTitle");
                     // if(streamTilleIndex <= 0){waitBitMetaData = 1;return;}
                      String streamTille = metaData.substring(streamTilleIndex);
                      int eqindex = streamTille.indexOf('=');
                   //   if(eqindex <= 0){waitBitMetaData = 1;return;}
                      int colindex = streamTille.indexOf(';');
                   //   if(colindex <= 0){waitBitMetaData = 1;return;}
                      String metaDatam =  streamTille.substring(eqindex, colindex);
                      int lengthOfMaetaDataM = metaDatam.length();
                      if(lengthOfMaetaDataM <= 0){waitBitMetaData = 1;return;}
                      metaDataParsed =metaDatam.substring(2, lengthOfMaetaDataM-2);
                      System.out.println(metaDataParsed);                         
                      waitBitMetaData = 1;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                waitBitMetaData = 1;

            }

            }
             });
             metaThread.start();
 metaThread.start();
        //while( metaDataParsed.equals("") || waitBitMetaData == 0){
            //try {
            //  Thread.sleep(50);
            //} catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //System.out.println(e);
            //}
        //}
        return metaDataParsed;

}
```

Comment: Could you please accurately format your question? In the code of the `private String getMetaData(final String mediaUrl)` I don't see any `return` statement at all...

Comment: ok, I edit the question ... The return statemnt at the last...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you are getting `null` with a `Thread` is you don't wait for the end of the thread execution. This is not related to BlackBerry, but is purely related to Java. To solve this just do the whole task (not just networking part of it) on a separate (from UI) thread. When upon task completion you'll need to update the UI, then just use `UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(Runnable action)` pattern.

Comment: I am developing a Online radio app,When my app loads its shows some texts in a list field, user click in these list elements some new list elements are generated to the same list filed,after some iterations we get some stream urls by parsing the json return by server , When I get a stream url I try to play it using a class using Player Object. And I try to extract metadata from this class.

Comment: I believe the "we get some stream urls by parsing the json return by server , When I get a stream url I try to play it using a class using Player Object. And I try to extract metadata from this class." should be a one task that is run on a separate thread. Then within the thread things will happen sequentially and thus you will not get unexpected nulls.